# Receiving: MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers using inbound-channel-adapter in 2 different spring integration modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have **2 spring integration context** files using similar file-based integration pattern. Both scan directory looking for a message and both work if deployed by themselves. If I include both modules into another spring context they are loading without issues. However only second one is working, and the first one is getting: **MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers**. I've attempted to combine them into a single context file with no positive gain. We are currently on version 2.1.3 of Spring Integration and version 2.1 of Spring Integration File. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
inpayment-context.xml:

<!-- START of in-bound message implementation -->
<int:channel id="file-inpayment-channel" datatype="java.io.File" />
<bean id="xmlPatternFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="*.xml" />
</bean>

<task:executor id="batchInBoundExecuter" pool-size="1-1" queue-capacity="20" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="file:${inpayment.inbox}" filter="xmlPatternFileListFilter"
    channel="file-inpayment-channel">
    <int:poller id="inPaymentrPoller" fixed-delay="1000" task-executor="batchInBoundExecuter" default="true" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="inPaymentService" class="com.somepackage.InPaymentBootstrapService" />
<int:service-activator id="batchJobLaunchService" ref="inPaymentService" input-channel="file-inpayment-channel"
    method="schedule" />

<!-- START of out-bound message implementation -->
<int:channel id="inpayment-file-out-channel" datatype="java.io.File" />
<int:gateway id="inboundPaymentGateway" service-interface="com.somepackage.InboundPaymentGateway"
    default-request-channel="inpayment-file-out-channel" />

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter directory="file:${inpayment.inprocess}" channel="inpayment-file-out-channel"
    auto-create-directory="true" delete-source-files="true" />
<!-- END of out-bound message implementation -->


scheduler-context.xml:
<!-- START of in-bound message implementation -->
<int:channel id="scheduler-file-in-channel" datatype="java.io.File" />
<bean id="simplePatternFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="*.xml" />
</bean>

<task:executor id="batchJobRunExecuter" pool-size="1-1" queue-capacity="20" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="file:${scheduler.inbox}" filter="simplePatternFileListFilter"
    channel="scheduler-file-in-channel">
    <int:poller id="schedulerPoller" fixed-delay="5000" task-executor="batchJobRunExecuter" default="true" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="launchService" class="com.somepackage.BatchJobLaunchService" />
<int:service-activator id="batchJobLaunchService" ref="launchService" input-channel="scheduler-file-in-channel"
    method="schedule" />
<!-- END of in-bound message implementation -->

<!-- START of out-bound message implementation -->
<int:channel id="scheduler-file-out-channel" datatype="java.io.File" />
<int:channel id="scheduler-xml-out-channel" datatype="com.somepackage.ScheduledJob" />

<int:gateway id="batchJobSchedulerGateway" service-interface="com.innovation.customers.guideone.scheduler.integration.SchedulerGateway"
    default-request-channel="scheduler-xml-out-channel" />

<int:transformer input-channel="scheduler-xml-out-channel" output-channel="scheduler-file-out-channel" ref="schedulerFileTransformer"
    method="transformToFile" />
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter directory="file:${scheduler.completed}" channel="scheduler-file-out-channel"
    auto-create-directory="true" delete-source-files="true" />
<!-- END of out-bound message implementation -->


Common Spring Context:

<context:component-scan base-package="com.somepackage" /> 
<import resource="classpath:g1-scheduler-context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:g1-inpayment-context.xml"/>
```

**EDIT**

```
2014-08-27 11:01:01,530 ERROR [batchJobRunExecuter-1][:] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers. at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(Unica‌​stingDispatcher.java:108) at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(Unicast‌​ingDispatcher.java:101)
```

Comment: Show, please the logs when you get `Dispatcher has no subscribers`. Need to know the channel, which causes an issue.

Comment: Please find the error log below. If you know of a way of enhance the error log to show more information please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2014-08-27 11:01:01,530 ERROR [batchJobRunExecuter-1][:] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers.
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:108)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)

Comment: No, it's not enough. Switch on, please, DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` category and show more logs before ` Dispatcher has no subscribers`. BTW, you can simply edit your post. Let me move your log comments to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I see the issue in your config:

```
<int:service-activator id="batchJobLaunchService" ref="inPaymentService" input-channel="file-inpayment-channel"
    method="schedule" />
```

and

```
<int:service-activator id="batchJobLaunchService" ref="launchService" input-channel="scheduler-file-in-channel"
    method="schedule" />
```

They assume to be different services, but at the same time use the same `id` - `batchJobLaunchService`.

Spring by default allows to do that, but only the last bean definition with the same `id` wins. That's why the `<service-activator>` for the `launchService` hasn't been pupolated and hence the `EventDrivenConsumer` bean hasn't been subscribed to the `scheduler-file-in-channel`.

Be careful and use unique id for all your beans.

It isn't so easy to throw expection on the duplication case, but if you switch on INFO for the `org.springframework` category you'll the message that one bean overrrides another.

Comment: [Headers={timestamp=1409153164575, id=54d7201e-1490-455f-900a-8b470521c8dc}]
2014-08-27 11:26:04,578 DEBUG [batchJobRunExecuter-1][:] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel : preSend on channel 'scheduler-file-in-channel', message: [Payload=c:\IG\Integrations\Batch\Scheduler\INBOX\batch-jobs.xml][Headers={timestamp=1409153164575, id=54d7201e-1490-455f-900a-8b470521c8dc}]
2014-08-27 11:26:04,580 DEBUG [batchJobRunExecuter-1][:] org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel : preSend on channel 'errorChannel

Comment: , message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers.][Headers={timestamp=1409153164580, id=5576859f-729a-4bc3-bf67-48dc685eee9a}]
2014-08-27 11:26:04,581 DEBUG [batchJobRunExecuter-1][:] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : (inner bean)#12 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers.][Headers={timestamp=1409153164580, id=5576859f-729a-4bc3-bf67-48dc685eee9a}]

Comment: It worked .. Artem, thanks so much! Its great to receive support from the beloved city of my youth

Comment: Я не вижу где нажать Accept? May be I don't have "sufficient reputation"?

Comment: Hm... It should be leftward from my `I see the issue in your config:` phrase. Zero between two arrows. OK, nevermind: the main goal has been achieved - the fix of the issue!

Comment: I will get it ... right now it tells me that I don't have 15 points in my reputation. Thanks again